# Create circle DIV with dividers using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

is there any way to create a circle div with dividers/segments using jquery?

basically, somehting like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYvzd/118/light/)

```js
/*  
 *  This jquery plugin is based on this blogpost - http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas
 *  If you want to know more how it works, please refer to the above tutorial. 
 *  
 *  @author Roy Yu | iroy2000 [at] gmail.com ( modify, repackage and add new features )
 *  @description: This jquery plugin will create a spin wheel and let you to add players at run time. 
 *  
 */


(function($){
    $.fn.spinwheel = function(options, callback){
        
        var params = $.extend({},$.fn.spinwheel.default_options, options), $that = $(this), ctx = null, colorCache = [],
        startAngle = 0, arc = Math.PI / 6, spinTimeout = null, spinArcStart = 10, spinTime = 0, spinTimeTotal = 0, spinAngleStart = 0, pplArray = params.pplArray, pplLength = pplArray.length;

        if($.isFunction(options)){
            callback = options;
            options = {};
        } 
        
        var methods = {
            init: function() {
                methods.getContext();
                methods.setup();
                drawWheel();                
            },       
            setup: function() {
                $(params.spinTrigger).bind('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    methods.spin();
                });
                                              
                $(params.addPplTrigger).bind('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var item = $('<li />').append($(params.joiner).val());
                    $(params.paricipants).append(item);
                    methods.updatePanel();
                });
                
                
            },            
            getContext: function() {         
                if(ctx !== null)
                    return ctx;

                var canvas = $that[0];
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");          
            },
            spin: function() {
                spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
                spinTime = 0;
                spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
                rotateWheel();                
            },
            updatePanel: function() {
                var $ppl = $(params.paricipants).children();  
                pplArray = [];
                $ppl.each(function(key, value){
                    pplArray.push(value.innerHTML);
                });
                arc = 2 * Math.PI / $ppl.length;
                pplLength = $ppl.length;
                drawWheel();
            }
        }
                                     
        function genHex(){
            var colors=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"], color = "", digit = [], i;

            for (i=0;i<6;i++){
                digit[i]=colors[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];             
                color = color+digit[i];     
            }   
            
            if($.inArray(color, colorCache) > -1){
                genHex();
            } else {
                colorCache.push('#'+color);
                return '#'+color;
            }
        }
        
       var rotateWheel = function rotateWheel() {
                spinTime += 30;
                if(spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
                    stopRotateWheel();
                    return;
                }

                var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
                startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
                drawWheel();
                spinTimeout = setTimeout(rotateWheel, 30);
        }
        
        function stopRotateWheel () {
                clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
                var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
                var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
                var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
                ctx.save();
                ctx.font = params.resultTextFont;
                var text = pplArray[index];
                $(params.winnerDiv).html(text).show();
                //ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
                ctx.restore();
            }         
        
        function drawArrow() {
            ctx.fillStyle = params.arrowColor;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (params.outterRadius + 15));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (params.outterRadius + 15));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (params.outterRadius - 15));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (params.outterRadius - 15));
            ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (params.outterRadius - 23));
            ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (params.outterRadius - 15));
            ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (params.outterRadius - 15));
            ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (params.outterRadius + 15));
            ctx.fill();               
        }
        
        function drawWheel() {
            ctx.strokeStyle = params.wheelBorderColor;
            ctx.lineWidth = params.wheelBorderWidth;
            ctx.font = params.wheelTextFont;            
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
            var text = null, i = 0, totalJoiner = pplLength;
            for(i = 0; i < totalJoiner; i++) {
                text = pplArray[i];           
                var angle = startAngle + i * arc;                
                ctx.fillStyle = colorCache.length > totalJoiner ? colorCache[i] : genHex();
                
                ctx.beginPath();
                // ** arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startingAngle, endingAngle, antiClockwise);
                ctx.arc(250, 250, params.outterRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
                ctx.arc(250, 250, params.innerRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.fill();
        
                ctx.save();
                ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
                ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
                ctx.shadowBlur    = 1;
                ctx.shadowColor   = params.wheelTextShadowColor;
                ctx.fillStyle = params.wheelTextColor;
                ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * params.textRadius, 250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * params.textRadius);
                ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
                
                ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
                ctx.restore();
                ctx.closePath();
            }       
            drawArrow();
        }          
  
        function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
            var ts = (t/=d)*t;
            var tc = ts*t;
            return b+c*(tc + -3*ts + 3*t);
        } 
                
        methods.init.apply(this,[]);
    }
    
    /*  ---  please look at the index.html source in order to understand what they do ---
     *  outterRadius : the big circle border
     *  innerRadius  : the inner circle border
     *  textRadius   : How far the the text on the wheel locate from the center point
     *  spinTrigger  : the element that trigger the spin action 
     *  wheelBorderColor : what is the wheel border color
     *  wheelBorderWidth : what is the "thickness" of the border of the wheel
     *  wheelTextFont : what is the style of the text on the wheel
     *  wheelTextColor : what is the color of the tet on the wheel
     *  wheelTextShadow : what is the shadow for the text on the wheel
     *  resultTextFont : it is not being used currently
     *  arrowColor : what is the color of the arrow on the top
     *  participants : what is the container for participants for the wheel
     *  joiner : usually a form input where user can put in their name
     *  addPplTrigger : what element will trigger the add participant
     *  winDiv : the element you want to display the winner
     */
    $.fn.spinwheel.default_options = {
        outterRadius:200, innerRadius:3, textRadius: 160, spinTrigger: '.spin-trigger', 
        wheelBorderColor: 'black',wheelBorderWidth : 3, wheelTextFont : 'bold 15px sans-serif', wheelTextColor: 'black', wheelTextShadowColor : 'rgb(220,220,220)',
        resultTextFont : 'bold 30px sans-serif', arrowColor :'black', paricipants:'.participants', addPplTrigger:'.add', joiner:'.joiner', winnerDiv:'.winner'
    }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.canvas').spinwheel({
       pplArray : ["♈", "♉", "♊", "♋","♌", "♍", "♎", "♏","♐", "♑", "♒", "♓"]
   });
});
```

```css
#main {
    width:1000px;
}

#left-column {
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    padding-right:15px;
}

#right-column {
    float:right;
    width:300px;
}

.participants {
    list-style:none;
}

.participants li {
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:15px;
    font-family: 'Carter One', arial, serif;
    font-size:150%;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
}

.participants li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color:#bada55;
}

.winner {
    font-family: 'Carter One', arial, serif;
    font-size:250%;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;    
    display:none;
}

.winner:before {
    content: "The Winner is ... "
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
            <div id="left-column">
                <form class="iform" action="#" method="get">
                    <label for="joiner"></label>
                    <input id="joiner" name="joiner" class="joiner" placeholder="Please Enter your name" />
                    <button class="add">Add</button>
                    <button class="spin-trigger">Spin</button>
                </form>        
                <canvas class="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas> 
            </div>
            <div id="right-column">
                <p class="winner">The Winner is ... <span>&nbsp;</span></p>
                <ul class="participants">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            
            
        </div>
```

I can use the code above but it is HTML5 and I'm trying to keep clear of the HTML5 in my project so it would be great to do this using Jquery as it will give me more freedom in terms of using external images and I wont have to fiddle about with canvas and all that in html5.

I just need to create a the circle div and divide based on the users input and let the users to choose the background colour on each segment>

I did try this with the code above in jsfiddle and I can let the user to even choose the background colour of the segment but there are some bugs which led me to think its best to use jquery.

example based on the code in jsfiddle above:

```
    for (i=0;i<1;i++){
        digit[i]=colors[Math.round(Math.random()*1)];             
        //color = color+digit[i];

         color = document.getElementById("colour").value; 

         //color = color+digit[i];     
    }
```

any advise would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am trying to modify the code bellow.

basically, what i am trying to do is to let the users to choose the colours of segments.

this is the original jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kYvzd/118/light/

so what i've done so far is this:

edited the HTML and added this to it:

```
            <select id="colour" name="colour" class="colour">

            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="db0000">Red</option>
            <option value="171515">Black</option>
             <option value="008c0a">Green</option>



            </select>
```

edited the javascript and added this:

```
    for (i=0;i<1;i++){
        digit[i]=colors[Math.round(Math.random()*1)];             
        //color = color+digit[i];

         color = document.getElementById("colour").value; 

         //color = color+digit[i];     
    }
```

the issue that I am facing right now is very strange. 
basically with my edit, it will add the segments but it doesn't add the colours properly! it will add the 1st segment with its colour properly, it will add the 2nd segment with its colour properly too and the issue starts from adding the third segment... it will add the segment but it will not add the colour properly! it will jump back to the previous background colour for the previous segment!

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid HTML5?

Comment: @EthanBrown, 1st, because I don't know anything about HTML5 and I am struggling to with it, 2nd, because In my project, I need to use external images and using images in HTML5 is not as easy as <img src="imag.jpg" /> etc etc.... there are so many pointless preparations to achieve a simple task such as using an external image...

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about HTML5; it is not hard to use at all, and simplifies a number of things.  And it *is* as easy as `<img src="image.jpg">` in HTML5 -- that's exactly how you add an image.  HTML5 has added support for images of different resolutions, but the `<img>` tag works just like it always has.  I think you should get on the HTML5 bandwagon -- it is no harder than HTML 4.01/XHTML, and in many ways easier.  And it is ubiquitous now.  I *strongly* recommend Mark Pilgrim's http://diveintohtml5.info/.

Comment: @EthanBrown, adding an image to html5 page is similar to any other html pages but adding an image to html5 `canvas` is not as easy as just typing <img src > etc etc and the image will magically appear in the canvas and that is what I am referring to!

Comment: I see.  You're conflating `<canvas>` and HTML5.  You can use HTML5 without canvas.  What I think you *really* mean to say, then, is "I don't want to use canvas."  I wouldn't want to use the raw canvas API either -- it's pretty bare-bones.  But lots of good libraries build on it, as people have pointed out in this post.  Don't confuse canvas and HTML5, though.

Answer (score 0):

This library looks pretty good:

http://www.openstudio.fr/lab/Library-for-simple-drawing-with.html?lang=fr

```
$("#example3").fillArc(0, 0, 100, 45, 260, {color: '#ffa500'})
              .fillArc(0, 0, 100, 260, 310, {color: '#00c7ee'})
              .fillArc(0, 0, 100, 310, 45, {color: '#46aa08'});
```

Comment: I have used that plugin before but that is a very bloated plugin and it has quite a few bugs and because its provided For free, it has no support! So it is not a good plugin.

Comment: I was hoping to do this without any plugin as it will give me more freedom otherwise I could use HTML5.

Comment: To do drawing on the client, you need either canvas or svg. An alternative would be to make the image on the back end using php gd library or similar.